Kernel of a modules aplication
Let $A$ be a ring, $I$ an $A$-ideal. We define the aplication $A/I\otimes _AM\longrightarrow M/IM$, $[a]\otimes x\longmapsto [ax]$. I want to see it is injective.
My try is the following: let $[a]\in A/I$, $x\in M$ such that $[ax]=[0]$, that is, $ax\in IM$. Since $x\in M$, it has to be $a\in I$, and therefore, $[a]=[0]$. Thus, $[a]\otimes x=[0]\otimes x=0$, and the aplication is injective since its Ker is ${0}$.
I'm not sure about ensuring $a\in I$, but I've found no other way of proving it. Is my approach correct?

There are a few problems here. First of all, not every element of the tensor product is a simple tensor, but a finite sum of simple tensors. Also, $ax\in IM$ doesn't imply $a\in I$. It only means the element $ax$ can be written as a finite sum of the form $\sum a_ix_i$ with $a_i\in I, x_i\in M$. So your proof doesn't work at all. In order to prove the claim, I suggest to construct an inverse map, it is pretty natural.

I see what I need to prove: if $[y]\in M/IM$, then there exists $[a]\in A/I, x\in M$, such that $[y]=[ax]$, and then map back $[y]=[ax]\longmapsto [a]\otimes x$. But how can I grant the existence of such $[a], x$?
